# My Dell laptop has Nvidia GPU but it runs on Intel graphics

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, nvidia-geforce, dell-xps

I have [Dell XPS L502x](http://www.dell.com/us/p/xps-l502x/pd.aspx) and I bought which has *2GB NVIDIA GeForce GT 540M Graphics card*

[image]

But it runs on Intel Graphics

[image]

How to use Nvidia Graphics instead Intel Graphics?

Comment: I'm fairly certain you can force it to use the Nvidia card from the Nvidia control panel (look under power savings options).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your laptop has [Nvidia Optimus](http://www.nvidia.com/object/optimus_technology.html) Technology ([Dell help page](http://content.dell.com/us/en/home/d/help-me-choose/hmc-nvdia-graphics.aspx?dgc=CO&cid=63294&lid=1585388)):

> NVIDIA Optimus technology (not
>   available on 3D panel)
>
> NVIDIA® Optimus™ technology
>   automatically optimizes your battery
>   life while maintaining the graphics
>   performance you expect — completely,
>   seamlessly and transparently — whether
>   you’re watching a movie, surfing the
>   Web or playing a game.
>
> How does it work?
>
> - This intelligent graphics technology **switches between discrete
>     and integrated graphics processors
>     automatically whenever it determines
>     what kind of application is being
>     used. If you are simply surfing the
>     Web, the GPU switches to the
>     integrated version**, therefore helping
>     to extend your battery life. It's that
>     easy to experience long battery life
>     and amazing visuals without having to
>     manually change settings.
> - Watch an HD movie, surf the Web or play games knowing you can get the long battery life you need and the performance you expect from NVIDIA Optimus technology.

Basically your system is not using the Nvidia card because it doesn't *need* to.  If you were to start watching a HD movie or playing a game then it would switch to using the Nvidia hardware, the fact of the matter is that you're not doing anything that needs the Nvidia card to kick in so your laptop is saving power by turning off the Nvidia card and using the integrated graphics instead.

Answer (score 3):

You might need to configure NVidia Optimus to use dedicated NVidia graphics. Usually optimus will automatically switch when dedicated graphics are needed.